# Intermediate results in the new Async/Await commands

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I have been wondering...

Do the new Async constructs actually allow for intermediate results without writing new code on the consumer side?

Let me elaborate with an example.

Let's say we have a method that downloads data into a byte array or a stream, whichever is better.

Is it possible, that a method that `await`s said method can start consuming the byte array or stream before the download is complete with the built in async features? What I could do is raise events everytime a certain part of the stream is downloaded, but that increases clutter again.

Let me write a code example (from the top of my head, will not be correct code!) that I (would) expect to result in intermediate results, given the `await`ed method returns such results.

```
io.Stream data = await downloadData();
byte[4096] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (!data.EOF) {
  (await?) data.Read(buffer, offset, 4096);
}
```

As of now, `Stream.Read` is *not* awaitable, do we have any method of doing this, though? I want to be able to `await` through a transfer. Am I overseeing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `Stream` in .Net 4.5, you can use its [`ReadAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this:

```
Stream stream = await downloadData();
byte[4096] buffer = new byte[4096];
int read;
do
{
    read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    // do something with buffer here
} while (read > 0);
```

If you mean that your stream does not have a method such as `ReadAsync()`, but does support asynchrony using the `BeginXxx()`, `EndXxx()` pattern, and you want to use `await`, then you can do that too:

```
do
{
    read = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<byte[], int, int, int>(
        stream.BeginRead, stream.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);
    // do something with buffer here
} while (read > 0);
```

But, if you only have a synchronous `Read()` method, the only way to use it with `async` would be to start a new `Task` on a background thread:

```
do
{
    read = await Task.Run(() => stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
    // do something with buffer here
} while (read > 0);
```

The problem with this code is that it still blocks a thread, which is what `async` is trying to avoid. But it might still be useful if the method runs on a GUI thread, and you can't run the whole loop on a background thread.

Comment: +1: A `Task<T>` cannot return a partial result. The solution is to only ask for a portion of the result, a la `.Read()`, which `Task<T>` can fully satisfy.

Comment: Awesome so far, I'm sad though that there's no awesome pattern for partial results from ONE Task<T>. So we need to make HttpWebRequests, get the stream and do `Request.GetResponseAsync` and use your first pattern on the resulting stream. It's still better than having to run either one of those callbacks or a `Thread` :D

Comment: @sinni800, I don't see how would getting a partial result from a `Task<T>` be better. I think that this way, the interface is simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: @svick I see your point there. Maybe the team already considered it, but threw it away because of that?

Comment: @svick - It seems like if you want 'partial results' for something like this, then you're looking more for an observable and instead of task and it's one-time result, should get the stream to be an observable that 'fires' every X bytes (1KB or whatever)?  I'm an Rx n00b, so not sure if that makes sense or not.

Comment: @JamesManning, the difference is, `IObservable` uses push model, but I think pull model fits more naturally here.

Comment: @svick - maybe i'm thinking of it the wrong way, but in this kind of scenario (where you want chunks along the way), it sounds like you're asking for a push model.  IOW, instead of having to keep starting a new task after the last one completes, you really want something to go off and read the file, then push each chunk of it to you as it has been read.  Doing so as a single operation ('read file async as observable of chunks') seems to make more sense to me than create/await N different tasks - admittedly, using the Rx blog post image as guidance. :)

Comment: Interesting - looks like JeffVa already covered this in a series of blog posts.  Here's Part 1 of the series: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffva/archive/2010/07/23/rx-on-the-server-part-1-of-n-asynchronous-system-io-stream-reading.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really familiar enough with it to give you a good example, but since it sounds like you don't want a one-time result, but instead multiple results, that sounds like a better fit for observable.  Th[enter link description here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx)is image from the Rx team's 2.0 beta blog post is extremely useful along those lines (IMHO).

[image]

Comment: OnNext? Now I can't decide! Both answers are suitable for different scenarios :D